# Is it possible to pass a base64 string to define the icon inside a Manifest.json?

Tags: html, dom, progressive-web-apps, w3c

Like this:

```
{
  "theme_color": "#2196f3",
  "icon": "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7",
  "background_color": "#2196f3",
  "display": "browser",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/"
}
```

Also...
And if does work, would there be any limitations?
Which browser/platform might not accept that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't believe it is.

The icon property should also be an array of objects, containing `src`, `type`, and `sizes`, for example:

```json
"icons": [
  {
    "src": "/images/icons-192.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "192x192"
  },
  {
    "src": "/images/icons-512.png",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "512x512"
  }
],
```

See [Add a web app manifest](https://web.dev/add-manifest/) on web.dev for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
As said, 'icons' property is an array and in 'src' property you can set your base64 string with png data image format:

```
"icons": [
  {
    "src": "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "192x192"
  },
  {
    "src": "data:image/png;base64,XXXXXXXX.......",
    "type": "image/png",
    "sizes": "512x512"
  }
],
```